# How to load csv with double quotes, comma, and new line in some columns in SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I need to load a csv file with double quotes, comma, and new line in the memo/transcript column. I have tried to use the " as the text qualifier but it is not working because there is also a double quote inside the column. Please see example of the format below:

```
column1, column2, transcript, column4
column1text, column2text, "Example text, You can find more information in our <a href=""https://www.examplewebsite.com"">Website</a>.
You're now chatting with agentname<br/><br/>
11:00:00 agentname: Hi how may I help you?
11:00:06 customername: I have a complaint...
", column4text
```

Comment: first of all you need to change the delimiter from a comma to something else like like NCHAR(9999), which is a pencil (✏)

Answer (score 0):

What I did was I added a script task and used **Regex** and **MatchEvaluator** in System.Text.RegularExpressions namespace to match and replace the new line and comma then create a cleaned file.

**Regex:**

```
\"(.|\n)*?[^\"]\",
```

It will look for the pattern opening double quote, any character and new line in between, closing double quote and then comma. It will also look for the next closing double quote and comma if there are 2 double quotes before the comma.

[For Regex reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference?view=netframework-4.8)